# Difference between an Arbitrary collection and a Set.

Tags: functional-analysis

I'll give you the full context.
The Uniform boundedness Principle states that:
*Let $E$ be a Banach space and let $(T_i)_{i\in I}$ be a collection of linear, bounded operators from E to F (F is also a normed space) satisfying, $$\sup_{i \in I}||T_i(x)||< \infty, \forall x \in E$$
Then, $$\exists M>0 : \forall i \in I ,||T_i|| \le M$$.* 
My question is if I find a Set B of Bounded linear operators, satisfying the hypothesis, i.e. $$\sup_{f\in B}||f(x)|| < \infty,\forall x \in E$$
Then can i conclude
$$\exists M>0 : \forall f \in B, ||f|| \le M?$$